# Need to store my 4 digit encrypted PIN in keystore

Tags: android, android-keystore, android-security

I just Googled about store PIN in `key store`. I got confused for the most of the solution. here is my question :-

I have a encrypted PIN (string).

How to store it in keystore and retrieve it. I know about shared preference and some local storage. but I heard that key store is more secure.

So my question is how to store a string in `keystore` and retrieve from it.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27320610/how-can-i-use-the-android-keystore-to-securely-store-arbitrary-strings

Answer (score 0):

The Android Keystore system lets you store cryptographic keys in a container to make it more difficult to extract from the device. Once keys are in the keystore, they can be used for cryptographic operations with the key material remaining non-exportable. Moreover, it offers facilities to restrict when and how keys can be used, such as requiring user authentication for key use or restricting keys to be used only in certain cryptographic modes. See Security Features section for more information.

The Keystore system is used by the KeyChain API as well as the Android Keystore provider feature that was introduced in Android 4.3 (API level 18). This document goes over when and how to use the Android Keystore provider.

here you have all the data you need about how to it right!

[click here](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore.html#SecurityFeatures)

hope it's help you :)